# Sending ROS Nodes between Android Activities

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a ROS node that I want to be able to communicate with from a view class in an android app. This view class is outside of the mainActivity. At present, I believe that I must either:

1. create the node in the mainActivity and then send it, or a pointer to it, down a line of activities to the view that will communicate with it.
2. create the node in the view class that will directly communicate with it.

I believe that, with the second option, I will need to send either the nodeMainExecutor or a reference to it.

Any help or comments would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33559/sending-ros-nodes-between-android-activities/) by [Srogacki](https://answers.ros.org/users/1660/srogacki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2012-05-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You do not need to create nodes manually. Instead, build a class (for example, a View) that implements the [`NodeMain`](http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/source/browse/rosjava/src/main/java/org/ros/node/NodeMain.java) interface. In your activity's `init(NodeMainExecutor nmExecutor)` method, call

`nmExecutor.execute(yourView, yourNodeConfig);`

as shown on lines 48 and 51 of the [example activity](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/android_core/html/getting_started.html#using-rosactivity).

Your class should implement the methods from both `NodeMain` and [`NodeListener`](http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/source/browse/rosjava/src/main/java/org/ros/node/NodeListener.java) as [shown](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/getting_started.html#creating-nodes) in the rosjava documentation. You will receive the actual node object in your `onStart(ConnectedNode node)` method; you can add topic and service interactions there.

Note that you should NOT rely on `onStart()` running immediately; if you want to interact with the node from your activity (*e.g.*, to call a service you have created), check to make sure the node has actually been created first.

---

Originally posted by [jatowler](https://answers.ros.org/users/934/jatowler/) with karma: 61 on 2012-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Views should implement NodeMain and be executed by the NodeMainExecutor. See the android_tutorial_pubsub for an example and the android_core documentation: http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/android_core/html/index.html

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-05-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1